# Имитация выполнения MySQL скрипта

Tags: phpmyadmin, php, mysql

Есть ли какой-либо способ сделать имитацию выполнения скрипта в БД mysql? То есть, если у меня есть что-то типа `DELETE FROM catalog WHERE id = '1'`, то у меня не будут удалены записи с ID равному одному, а просто выведется на экран результат выполнения скрипта.

В нашем распоряжении есть PhpMyAdmin и прочие web инструменты.

Comment: Слабо могу представить что может << вывести на экран >> команда DELETE? кроме << TRUE / FALSE >>?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Здравствуйте. А не проще сделать через SELECT?
Например:

```
<?php
$a = mysql_fetch_row(mysql_query("SELECT id FROM catalog WHERE id = '1'"));
if($a[0] == true)
    echo "Удаление выполнено было бы, если хотел меня удалить ;-)";
?>
```

Comment: Ладно, сойдет за ответ, раз нельзя подругому

Comment: только используйте хотя бы mysqli

Answer (score -1):

```
BEGIN;
DELETE FROM catalog WHERE id = '1'
SELECT * FROM catalog WHERE id = '1'
ROLLBACK;
```

Только результата у этого запроса пустой, но это правильно)